# Parse different date with same format

Tags: java, android

In Api response getting date format :
**for user 1-

```
 "date": "2022-10-13T00:00:00+02:00[Africa/Johannesburg]".
```

for user 2-

```
"date": "2022-10-02T13:55:50.283+05:30[+05:30]**
```

How can we parse both date with single format?

Answer (score 3):

Both the dates are in format [`ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME), so can parse them using `ZonedDateTime`:

```
ZonedDateTime user1 = ZonedDateTime.parse("2022-10-13T00:00:00+02:00[Africa/Johannesburg]");
ZonedDateTime user2 = ZonedDateTime.parse("2022-10-02T13:55:50.283+05:30[+05:30]");
```

Or if you want to use `OffsetDateTime`, then you have to use the `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
OffsetDateTime user1 = OffsetDateTime.parse(
        "2022-10-13T00:00:00+02:00[Africa/Johannesburg]",
        DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME
);
OffsetDateTime user2 = OffsetDateTime.parse(
        "2022-10-02T13:55:50.283+05:30[+05:30]",
        DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME
);
```